# Jquery click function to print href question

Tags: jquery, printing, click

I have a print icon, using Jqueryui that I am trying to integrate with a Jquery print plugin called jqprint. I want to print the href when the icon is clicked

Html is:

```
<div class="item">
<a href="slides/image.jpg" title="Image"><img src="thumbs/image.jpg" /></a>
<<span class="printImage ui-icon ui-icon-print" title="Print Image"></span>
</div>
```

Button code:

```
$("span.printImage").live('click', function() {
$('.item a[href]').jqprint();
return false;
});
```

This code prints the entire page of thumbnails, not the href for that particular ".item" .
Any help would be appreciated. I am using live because I have some dynamic changes happening  on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('.item a[href]').jqprint();` Isn't going to work simply because that is not how jqPrint is designed to print an element's attributes. It is designed to print an element. What you have will print all anchors with the class `.item` and the `href` attribute defined. How about this:

```
var link = $(this).parents(".item.isotope-item").children("a").attr("href");

var img = $("<img />", { src: link }).appendTo("body");

img.load(function(){
    img.jqprint();
    img.remove();
});
```

Final answer :D

Comment: Close but it prints the href as text, not the image.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the element issue. I tried to target a hidden div with the image src in the div but that came up blank as well.

Comment: Works… except that it only prints the first image, i.e, the same image shows for every .item print icon I click. This is as far as i got with my hidden div option as well

Comment: The same image shouldn't show for every anchor, unless they all have the same href.

Comment: I agree but it seems to. Here is a link to jsfiddle to show the results. I set all the href's to 600x600 except the first one (80x80). When you click the print icons ( click show icons to see them), all the resulting images to print are the same 80x80 image. http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/fa2mS/

Comment: Just gives me a blank page with header and footer. Darn. Thanks so much for your efforts, tho! Your code seems like it should work.

Comment: Very wierd. I tested in Firefox and Safari in Mac and PC as well as IE and all popup a blank page and print out one as well.I even tried a real image instead of a placeholder. Not sure why it doesn't work for me, but I appreciate your help!        http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/fa2mS/15/

Answer (score 1):

`$('.item a[href]').jqprint();` is going to call `jqprint()` on all anchor elements that have an `href` attribute specified.

That will cause it to happen on all the anchors on the page naturally, what do you mean by print the `href` specified, do you mean print the resource at the location the anchor is pointing to?

If your goal is to call `jqprint()` on the anchor before the span you could try something like this, although this will be dependent on your html structure...

```
$("span.printImage").live('click', function() {
    $(this).prev().jqprint(); // or $(this).prevAll("a:first").jqprint();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to print the image in the href ( a large version of a thumbnail). I tried setting up a hidden div for each .item with the specific image in it but i just get a blank page with that.

Comment: @Mike try one of the lines in the example I posted, the `prevAll()` one will probably yield better results.

Comment: Niether seemed to target the image.

Comment: @Mike well I have to say i'm not familiar with jqprint and I can't find much info about it online, but if it was meant to print the image itself you could try something like this... `$("<img />").attr("src", $(this).prevAll("a:first").attr("href")).jqprint()` which is effectively creating a new image from the href of the link.

Comment: jqprint is no longer online, site down. I tried jquery printelement as well but no luck there for some reason. Thanks for you suggestions!